# Iframe Submission then Redirect

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

How can i make an iframe keep its default submission but after redirect the user to another page.  I have heard i need to do this redirection on the server side but do not know what this means.

Below is what i tried but it cancels the default iframe submission and just redirects.

```
function convert() {
            document.location = '/sidingsuccess';
}
```

with

```
onSubmit="convert();"
```

on the iframe code

Comment: You need to explain better.. when people click the form in your iframe, where do you want the page '/sidingsuccess' be loaded? in that same iframe? or full page in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

On the server you can, after your submission is finished, use the `header` function to redirect the page to another page (say `example.php`) by doing:

```
header('Location: example.php');
```

is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes so i need to just put onsubmit="header ();" on the iframe?

Comment: header is a php function, you would have to call it on the server.  You can't call it on the client. Just add it to the end of the php page dealing with your submission.

Comment: i don't have a page that deals with the submission, the iframe sends submission to an affiliate company.  I want the redirection to track conversions but have no control over the iframe code

Answer (score 1):

Submit form to hidden iframe.

iframe HTML:

```
<g:form controller="..." action="submit" method="POST" target="hidden-frame">
...
</g:form>

<iframe id="hidden-frame" style="display: none" onload="onSubmitCompleted"></iframe>

<script>
    function onSubmitCompleted() {
        window.top.location.href = <redirect url>
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
/*process submission */

render("<html><head><script>window.parent.onSubmitCompleted();</script></head><body></body></html>");
```

Comment: so the iframe form i am hosting should submit how it would normally but then redirect without screwing up the submission?

Comment: that's whole idea. The hidden iframe helps you to stay on page after submission

Comment: ok so the <form> code is meant to go in my iframe then the <iframe> code you have goes below? and where does the controller code go?

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, but there have to be code/method processing your submission. That method should response a string used in render method. You can even pass result to onSubmitCompleted js fn if you change string to ...onSubmitCompleted(eval(${result}))... I used json for result. If you passing true/false than you could omit eval.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your following line:

```
document.location = '/sidingsuccess';
```

for this one:

```
window.top.location.href = '/sidingsuccess';
```

that should do it.