# Load simple embed iframe in html and then php redirect

Tags: php, html, redirect, iframe

I know this question was asked before, but the answer was not 100% clear.
I have a very simple html page that loads an iframe, I want after this, to load a simple php redirection.

so i did:

```
<iframe width="1" height="1" src="http://cookie.com"></iframe>
<?php
header("Location: https://example.com);
exit();
?>
```

I supposed that put a header("Location right after the embed iframe would work, but the page never redirects due to the load of the iframe.
 What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: What answer did you look at? And what was not clear about it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501604/iframe-submission-then-redirect

Comment: Im not looking exactly the same as the user on the link above, but  just to load a cookie  which is contained on the site that the embed iframe holds, then redirect to an specific site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see why you would load the iframe and leave the page. In your `header("Location: https://example.com)`, you did not close the quotation mark.

Comment: That's just a mistake of typing here, sorry about that, in the original code the quotation mark is close.

Comment: Unless you must use the php, why not consider javascript to redirect to the mentioned website. Delete that php code and replace with `<script>window.location = "http://www.example.com";</script>`

Comment: Still doesn't do the trick, reads the embed code, but it doesnt move from there.